# How do I update my core project when using composer?

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I recently started a project using composer for the first time, and I just deployed it to Q&A (demo), with git I used to just do a `git pull` and update the Q&A environment, but now with `composer update` only the dependencies get updated.

My question is, what is the SOP(standard operating procedure) for updating the core project, do I still use git, or is there a way to do it with composer?

Or am I completely doing this wrong, and should be working out of the vendors folder?

Comment: what i do is  make a cronjob that executes every x days/months which updates the dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of Composer is that you *don't* need to version control the dependencies which means anything that ends up in `vendor/`.

The project has a `composer.json` and `composer.lock`. These are within git's control so it knows the packages and versions to use. However, the `vendor/` directory should be ignored, with `.gitignore`. If you don't already have that set up simply add this line:

```
/vendor/*
```

You version control your other files as normal.

So the operating procedure is to use git and normal. Followed by `composer update`.

The advantage of this setup is that git doesn't have to bother managing potentially thousands of files (inside `vendor/`) that will never normally change. The only circumstance under which they'd change is if you want to start using a *different* version of a package, or adding new ones. Well, all of those packages/versions are defined in your `composer.json` (which git is monitoring for changes). All you need to do is run `composer update` and it will update everything in your `vendor/` directory to the "right" version.

That's one of the advantages of using Composer - all developers can have a "list" of the correct packages/versions, without the need to version control all of the files in them.

**Edit** as per the comments below:

Note `composer update` should only be run in development. Use `composer install` when deploying to QA or production. This will install the exact versions referenced by your `composer.lock` file.

Comment: Note `composer update` should only be run in development. Use `composer install` when deploying to QA or production. This will install the exact versions referenced by your `composer.lock` file. You don't want to be installing new and untested versions of dependencies in production.

Comment: Please update this answer to use `composer install` instead of `composer update` to install dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You keep using `git` for your project and `composer` for 3rd party libs.

I have a large web app in PHP (link in my profile), and that's how I've been doing it, and it works good.

When I have new production-ready code and it's ready to be released, I do:
`git fetch && git pull`

And when I want to update composer, I do:
`composer -o update`

I don't know if you're familiar with `-o` flag - it generates static autoloading maps, which makes your project load classes faster. More info [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/autoloader-optimization.md).